# Android: download from web in background

Tags: android, service, android-activity, background

I've the need to create a simple app that do this:
- every run try to download somewhat like 20 pdf from web (every time from the same location, because the server keep it updated every minute)
- the main activity will be only a list of pdf. One dir will be scanned for downloaded files. If there are any, then them will be listed.

The problem is I need to download 'in background', but not with a 'never-ending service'.

I'm thinking to create launch a sevice when application start. The main activty scan the dir e show the pdf, while the service try to download the pdf.

If the first time not all of the pdf are yet downloaded, is not a problem.

I tried to do this, but the service 'lock' the app, so the app is not responding.

I was thinking that service run into a separate thread. Is is real ?

So: wha't the best solution to have the activities running smooth, but in background 'something' download a lot of file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Android-AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Android-IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is best suited for your requirements.

If you will going to use AsyncTask you can update your Activity UI periodically while downloading continues.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to deeply check Intent Service conception. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

From one side, it's a service. That means that system will not probably kill the downloading when user will press "Home" from your app.
However, it is not

> never-ending service

As it will be finished exactly after downloading complete (If no more task will be launched).

And answering your question:

> I was thinking that service run into a separate thread. Is is real ?

This is not 100% true. If you just use `startService` and do a heavy task in Service.onCreate() - than it will hang your application, as it's running in UI Main thread.
However, if you'll extends IntentService - it has a convenient method to override `onHandleIntent` ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent )), which will be executed in separate thread. IntentService will do that for you.

Let me know if any questions.